# Can we extract only the text part from a pdf file using python by ignoring images and tables

Tags: python, pdf

def extract_first_lines_for_HTML(pdf_path):
extracted_data = []
non_extracted_data = []

```
with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
    for page_number in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        page = pdf.pages[page_number]

        # Adjust the crop box to exclude headers and footers
        crop_box = (left, top, page.width - int(right), page.height - int(bottom))  # Adjust margins as needed
        page_crop = page.within_bbox(crop_box)

        page_text = page_crop.extract_text(x_tolerance=1.5, y_tolerance=3.5)
        page_text = re.sub(r"(\∗)[\n\r]+(.*?)(\() (\))", r"\2\3*\4", page_text)

        lines_count = page_text.split('\n')
        # for the pages with figure
```

I'm working on a project were i have to get content from PDF and search on its corresponding HTML file Using this code i can extract the text from a pdf file only from a selected region (example: ignoring header and footer)

Problem I'm facing is sometimes I'm searching for text which is tagged as an image or table on HTML file to increase my accuracy I want to extract only the text part not the images and tables Please give me an idea if you have one

Comment: Package [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/) allows you to do that easily: `text = page.get_text(clip=rect)` returns only text contained in the clip rectangle. The clip parameter is also supported in text searching, detecting tables or rendering page to image. **Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Comment: In PyMuPDF you can also identify image, vector graphic and table locations and then extract only text that is not contained in any of these respective rectangles.

Comment: but even some image which is present as an image tag in the HTML file if that image has letters in it when it is in pdf file when extracting text text inside the image is also extracted i want to ignore image text is there a way

Comment: Text visible in an image is no text: it consists of pixels just like everything else in the image. I am assuming here that you do not talk about standard text that has been written **_over_** the image. If my assumption is correct: it seems like you want to modify the image itself such that text-like content is removed. **_This_** is possible too, by combining OCR techniques (for locating the "image-text") and redaction annotations. PyMuPDF's features cover both techniques. After redacting an image, it will show empty rectangles where there used to text.